# why I'm getting http headers along with my non-html data while reading a webpage using java?

Tags: java, html

I've tried several codes for getting data from internet but  all of them  will get the header along with the file that I'm trying to save:

like following code :

```
URL url;
String webURL = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EGLL/2010/11/30/DailyHistory.html?HideSpecis=1&format=1";
url = new URL(webURL);
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\weather.txt");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
```

but when I open the webURL in IE or FF everything is okay.

this is what I'll get from above code :

```
TimeGMT,TemperatureC,Dew PointC,Humidity,Sea Level PressurehPa,VisibilityKm,Wind Direction,Wind SpeedKm/h,Gust SpeedKm/h,Precipitationmm,Events,Conditions,WindDirDegrees,DateUTC<br />
12:20 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1031,10.0,WSW,22.2,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,250,2011-12-26 00:20:00<br />
12:50 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1031,10.0,WSW,24.1,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,250,2011-12-26 00:50:00<br />
1:20 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1031,10.0,WSW,25.9,-,N/A,,Overcast,250,2011-12-26 01:20:00<br />
1:50 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1032,10.0,West,24.1,-,N/A,,Overcast,260,2011-12-26 01:50:00<br />
2:20 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1032,10.0,WSW,22.2,-,N/A,,Overcast,250,2011-12-26 02:20:00<br />
2:50 AM,12,10,81,1032,35,WSW,25.9,,,,Overcast,250,2011-12-26 02:50:00<br />
2:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,22.2,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,250,2011-12-26 02:50:00<br />
3:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 03:20:00<br />
3:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,22.2,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 03:50:00<br />
4:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,250,2011-12-26 04:20:00<br />
4:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,18.5,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 04:50:00<br />
5:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1032,10.0,WSW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 05:20:00<br />
5:50 AM,12,10,84,1032,30,SW,20.4,,,,,220,2011-12-26 05:50:00<br />
5:50 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1032,10.0,SW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,220,2011-12-26 05:50:00<br />
6:20 AM,12.0,9.0,82,1033,10.0,SW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,230,2011-12-26 06:20:00<br />
6:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,SW,18.5,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,230,2011-12-26 06:50:00<br />
7:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,SW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,220,2011-12-26 07:20:00<br />
7:50 AM,11.0,9.0,88,1033,10.0,SW,22.2,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,230,2011-12-26 07:50:00<br />
8:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,SW,18.5,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,230,2011-12-26 08:20:00<br />
8:50 AM,12,10,86,1033,30,SW,18.5,,,,Mostly Cloudy,220,2011-12-26 08:50:00<br />
8:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,SW,16.7,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,230,2011-12-26 08:50:00<br />
9:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,WSW,18.5,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 09:20:00<br />
9:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1033,10.0,WSW,22.2,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 09:50:00<br />
10:20 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1034,10.0,WSW,24.1,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 10:20:00<br />
10:50 AM,12.0,10.0,88,1034,10.0,WSW,20.4,-,N/A,,Mostly Cloudy,240,2011-12-26 10:50:00<br />
Set-Cookie: DT=1324898571:20868:365-t1; path=/; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT; domain=.wunderground.com
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-cache="Set-Cookie", private
X-CreationTime: 0.352
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8


GMT,Max TemperatureC,Mean TemperatureC,Min TemperatureC,Dew PointC,MeanDew PointC,Min DewpointC,Max Humidity, Mean Humidity, Min Humidity, Max Sea Level PressurehPa, Mean Sea Level PressurehPa, Min Sea Level PressurehPa, Max VisibilityKm, Mean VisibilityKm, Min VisibilitykM, Max Wind SpeedKm/h, Mean Wind SpeedKm/h, Max Gust SpeedKm/h,Precipitationmm, CloudCover, Events,WindDirDegrees<br />
2011-12-26,12,12,11,10,10,9,88,86,81,1034,1032.40,1031,30.0,11.7,10.0,26,22,,0.0,6,,240<br />
```

Comment: Why don't you use, say, Apache Commons' HTTPClient? It will take care of headers for you

Answer (score 0):

If you read the RFC ([RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html)) you can see that all responses from a server (Http Responses that is) contain a header.

In a web browser this is all transparent to the user, because the response headers contain some information relevant to the content retrieved or the request made.

If you only want the content you must get the response entity from your message, ignoring the headers of said response, then that is saved into the file you want.

Comment: And "the headers" is simply everything up to the first empty line.

Comment: is there any specific method in java for getting only response?

Comment: You should use the Apache HttpComponents for the requests, there's lots of examples on how to start using it: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html